# Storing an ArrayList in an 2d Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

How can I store an ArrayList in a two dimensional array?

I've tried it like this, but it won't work:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer>[][] arr = new ArrayList<Integer>[9][9];
```

but it won't even let me declare the ArrayList-Array.

Is there a way to store a list in a 2d array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im a bit confused, do you want a 2d primitive array or a 2d arraylist, or an arraylist of primitive arrays?

Comment: I want an 2d array, in which i can store an arraylist. E.g. array[0][0]=arrayList1, array[0][1]=arrayList2 etc. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Try to use ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

Comment: primitive arrays can only store primitives

Comment: ok thank you, I'll try something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create arrays of generic types in Java. But this compiles:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer>[][] arr = (ArrayList<Integer>[][]) new ArrayList[9][9];
arr[0][0] = arrList;
```

Why can't you create these arrays? According to the Generics FAQ, [because of this problem](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?):

```
Pair<Integer,Integer>[] intPairArr = new Pair<Integer,Integer>[10]; // illegal 
Object[] objArr = intPairArr;  
objArr[0] = new Pair<String,String>("",""); // should fail, but would succeed
```

Comment: This helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an `ArrayList` inside an `ArrayList` inside yet another `ArrayList`, you can simply specify that in your type declaration:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> foo = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
```

Entries can be accessed via:

```
Integer myInt = foo.get(1).get(2).get(3);
```

Just be wary of boundaries - if you try to access an out of bounds index you'll see Exceptions thrown.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't want to store my ArrayList in another ArrayList. I'd like to know if it's possible to store a list in a 2d array, so that I alltogether get somthing 3d, if you know what i mean